# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter [timezone] =, org.apache.oozie.servlet.XServletException: E1003:

Tags: oozie

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter [timezone] =
>   [GMT+9] must be a valid TZ. Parsing error Invalid TimeZone: GMT+9
>           at org.apache.oozie.util.ParamChecker.checkTimeZone(ParamChecker.java:301)
>           at
>
> org.apache.oozie.command.coord.CoordSubmitXCommand.resolveInitial(CoordSubmitXCommand.java:693)
>           at org.apache.oozie.command.coord.CoordSubmitXCommand.basicResolveAndIncludeDS(CoordSubmitXCommand.java:581)
>           at org.apache.oozie.command.coord.CoordSubmitXCommand.submit(CoordSubmitXCommand.java:221)
>
> org.apache.oozie.servlet.XServletException: E1003: Invalid coordinator
>   application attributes, parameter [timezone] = [GMT+9] must be a valid
>   TZ. Parsing error Invalid TimeZone: GMT+9
>           at
>
> org.apache.oozie.servlet.V1JobsServlet.submitCoordinatorJob(V1JobsServlet.java:232)
>           at org.apache.oozie.servlet.V1JobsServlet.submitJob(V1JobsServlet.java:91)
>           at org.apache.oozie.servlet.BaseJobsServlet.doPost(BaseJobsServlet.java:99)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
>           at org.apache.oozie.servlet.JsonRestServlet.service(JsonRestServlet.java:287)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter$2.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:126)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:384)
>           at org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:131)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.oozie.servlet.HostnameFilter.doFilter(HostnameFilter.java:84)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

**Why this error message is generated???**?

Answer (score 0):

The [Oozie coordinator documentation](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2._Timezone_Representation) specifies that GMT-based timezones should be formatted as `GMT[+/-]##:##`, so you will want to specify your timezone as `GMT+09:00`.